# Is there a vim shortcut for <name of current file>?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, macro

In vim, if I'm working on a Python script, I will commonly type:

```
:! python this_script.py
```

to execute the script. Is there a shortcut for the name of the current file? If not, can I easily make one? I'm new at vim, and I'm not sure how to google for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just use `%` for current file. This command should serve your purpose:

```
:! python %
```

Comment: Thus, don't forget you must quote the `%` character when using commands like `:s` ... `:s/Foo\%X//` ... if you don't, the name of the file will show up there.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use the really nice package for vim: [Efficient python folding : Fold python code nicely and toggle with one keystroke](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494) which folds the "defs, classes" but also binds "shift+e" to 'save + execute', so cool and useful!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you are also using the embedded Python interpreter in Vim, you can get the name with the `vim.current.buffer.name` attribute. You man also want to use the :update command to write the file automatically. I have a mapping like for Python buffers:

```
nmap ;ru :update<CR>:python pyterm(vim.current.buffer.name)
```

The `pyterm` is a function that also opens a new Python interpreter in a new terminal window and runs it in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers

```
:h 'makeprg
:h :make
```