# How to compile a c program without leaving the editor?

Tags: vim, compiling, c

I am using vim editor on Linux mint. I want to know if there is any way to compile c program without leaving the editor.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

One method is to compile using

```
:!gcc file.c
```

But a nicer strategy would be to have a `Makefile` and compile just using

```
:make
```

Where the easiest `Makefile` would look like.

```
program:
        gcc file.c
```

[Others can explain this a lot better](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Writing-a-makefile.html).

Comment: According to [Is there a vim shortcut for <name of current file>?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14353/is-there-a-vim-shortcut-for-name-of-current-file), `:!gcc %` seems handier.

Comment: @manatwork That only works if the current file is actually the main program.

Comment: can you elaborate on the Makefile strategy please...

Comment: Correct. For other cases your second code should be preferred.

Comment: @user1614244 - step 1) learn to use make, step 2) invoke `:make`. Note however that you can set `makeprg` to the build tool of your choice

Answer (score 9):

The canonical way to do this in Vim is to use the **compiler** configuration setting.  Your vim installation almost certainly comes with a compiler plugin for **gcc**.  Type `:help compiler` in Vim to find out more about how this works.

To associate gcc with c source files, you need something like this in your .vimrc:

```
au BufEnter *.c compiler gcc
```

Comment: How would you go about invoking the compiler once you have set it?